# Textual Inversion, AttributeError: module 'main' has no attribute 'LearningRateMonitor'

Tags: python, torch

```
Loading model from {ckpt}
{self.class.name}: Running in {self.parameterization}-prediction mode
DiffusionWrapper has 872.30 M params.
making attention of type 'vanilla' with 512 in_channels
Working with z of shape (1, 4, 32, 32) = 4096 dimensions.
making attention of type 'vanilla' with 512 in_channels
Restored from {path} with {len(missing)} missing and {len(unexpected)} unexpected keys
Monitoring {model.monitor} as checkpoint metric.
Merged modelckpt-cfg:
{modelckpt_cfg}
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/media/server1/HDD1/textual-inversion/main.py", line 750, in
trainer_kwargs["callbacks"] = [instantiate_from_config(callbacks_cfg[k]) for k in callbacks_cfg]
File "/media/server1/HDD1/textual-inversion/main.py", line 750, in
trainer_kwargs["callbacks"] = [instantiate_from_config(callbacks_cfg[k]) for k in callbacks_cfg]
File "/media/server1/HDD1/textual-inversion/ldm/util.py", line 85, in instantiate_from_config
return get_obj_from_str(config["target"])(**config.get("params", dict()), **kwargs)
File "/media/server1/HDD1/textual-inversion/ldm/util.py", line 93, in get_obj_from_str
return getattr(importlib.import_module(module, package=None), cls)
AttributeError: module 'main' has no attribute 'LearningRateMonitor'
```

I had a problem reproducing TI's code according to the readme, and I couldn't solve it. I tried generating my own embedding with --base configs/latent-diffusion/txt2img-1p4B-finetune.yaml

TI is Textual Inversion (https://github.com/rinongal/textual_inversion)